# Combining Javascript counter OR click function in an if statement?

Tags: javascript, click, counter, logical-operators

I am creating a button which keeps count of the number of clicks. I would like specific information to show/hide depending on the number of clicks OR on the click of the navigation tabs above. I am attempting to combine a counter and a click function with (||), but I believe that I am setting it up incorrectly. How could I go about achieving the display on either of those events (counter || click of tab)?

```js
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $i = 0;
            $(".proceedBtn").click(function(){
                $i = $i + 1;
            });
            if ($i == 0) || $(".billing").click(function(){
                $('#billingQuestions').show();
                $('#billingQuestions2').show();
                $('#noQuestions').hide();
                $('#noQuestions2').hide();
                $('#paymentInfo').hide();
                $('#paymentInfo2').hide();
                $('.arrow').css('left', '15%');
            });
        });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per my understanding you want to hide and show mentioned controls based on counter value.ie if counter=1 those controls will be visible or not will be decided,if my this understanding is  correct try using below code

```
$(document).ready(function() {
            $i = 0;
});
           $(document). on("click",".proceedBtn", function(){
                $i = $i + 1;
            });

            $(document).
on("click",".billing",function(){
 if ($i == 0){
                $('#billingQuestions').show();
                $('#billingQuestions2').show();
                $('#noQuestions').hide();
                $('#noQuestions2').hide();
                $('#paymentInfo').hide();
                $('#paymentInfo2').hide();
                $('.arrow').css('left', '15%');
             }
            });
```